# How do I calculate the decibels from an mp3 file in R

Tags: r, mp3

I'm trying to determine the "loudness" of sound recordings in an mp3 file expressed as decibel (dB), but I'm completely stuck and haven't found any workable example.

So far all I've achieved is to read a file and plot the wave, but I'm not quite clear what values it is expressed in, nor whether I will be able to determine amplitude and audible decibel level from it.

```
library(tuneR)
knock <- tuneR::readMP3("C:/Users/davis/Desktop/Noise/knock.mp3")
plot(knock)
```

Please can someone help?

There are some sound snipped examples here if helpful:
https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3
https://file-examples.com/index.php/sample-audio-files/sample-mp3-download/

Comment: maybe soundgen::getLoudness

Comment: See the [soundgen vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/soundgen/vignettes/acoustic_analysis.html), especially the section on loudness. Decibels will depend on how the sound is generated from the digital representation (e.g. amplifier size, speaker size). You want the relative loudness.